# Table with mixed formats - long and wide

Tags: r, database

I have this table in which every variable has a certain number of classes. I would like to know the amount of observations that are in every class. All my variables are organized in long format, but one - `HINCFEL`. I want to transform the variable into long format, as all the other variables, and add a column with the count of observation: so for example i would know how many observations do I have for `GNDR` is 1 and at the same time `AGE` is 1 and at the same time `EDUC` is 1 and at the same time `ACTIVITY` is 1 and at the same time `HINCFEL` is 1.

```
structure(c("       ", "\"CNTRY\"", "\"BE\"   ", "       ", "       ", 
            "       ", "       ", "       ", "       ", "       ", "       ", 
            "       ", "       ", "       ", "       ", "       ", "       ", 
            "       ", "       ", "       ", "       ", "       ", "       ", 
            "       ", "       ", "       ", "       ", "       ", "       ", 
            "       ", "       ", "       ", "       ", "       ", "       ", 
            "       ", "       ", "       ", "       ", "       ", "       ", 
            "       ", "       ", "       ", "       ", "       ", "       ", 
            "       ", "       ", "       ", "       ", "       ", "      ", 
            "\"GNDR\"", "\"1\"   ", "      ", "      ", "      ", "      ", 
            "      ", "      ", "      ", "      ", "      ", "      ", "      ", 
            "      ", "      ", "      ", "      ", "      ", "      ", "      ", 
            "      ", "      ", "      ", "      ", "      ", "      ", "      ", 
            "      ", "      ", "      ", "      ", "      ", "      ", "      ", 
            "      ", "      ", "      ", "      ", "      ", "      ", "      ", 
            "      ", "      ", "      ", "      ", "      ", "      ", "      ", 
            "      ", "      ", "      ", "     ", "\"AGE\"", "\"1\"  ", 
            "     ", "     ", "     ", "     ", "     ", "     ", "     ", 
            "     ", "     ", "     ", "     ", "     ", "     ", "     ", 
            "\"2\"  ", "     ", "     ", "     ", "     ", "     ", "     ", 
            "     ", "     ", "     ", "     ", "     ", "     ", "     ", 
            "     ", "\"3\"  ", "     ", "     ", "     ", "     ", "     ", 
            "     ", "     ", "     ", "     ", "     ", "     ", "     ", 
            "     ", "     ", "\"4\"  ", "     ", "     ", "     ", "     ", 
            "      ", "\"EDUC\"", "\"1\"   ", "      ", "      ", "      ", 
            "      ", "\"2\"   ", "      ", "      ", "      ", "      ", 
            "\"3\"   ", "      ", "      ", "      ", "      ", "\"1\"   ", 
            "      ", "      ", "      ", "      ", "\"2\"   ", "      ", 
            "      ", "      ", "      ", "\"3\"   ", "      ", "      ", 
            "      ", "      ", "\"1\"   ", "      ", "      ", "      ", 
            "      ", "\"2\"   ", "      ", "      ", "      ", "      ", 
            "\"3\"   ", "      ", "      ", "      ", "      ", "\"1\"   ", 
            "      ", "      ", "      ", "      ", "          ", "\"ACTIVITY\"", 
            "\"1\"       ", "\"2\"       ", "\"3\"       ", "\"4\"       ", 
            "\"5\"       ", "\"1\"       ", "\"2\"       ", "\"3\"       ", 
            "\"4\"       ", "\"5\"       ", "\"1\"       ", "\"2\"       ", 
            "\"3\"       ", "\"4\"       ", "\"5\"       ", "\"1\"       ", 
            "\"2\"       ", "\"3\"       ", "\"4\"       ", "\"5\"       ", 
            "\"1\"       ", "\"2\"       ", "\"3\"       ", "\"4\"       ", 
            "\"5\"       ", "\"1\"       ", "\"2\"       ", "\"3\"       ", 
            "\"4\"       ", "\"5\"       ", "\"1\"       ", "\"2\"       ", 
            "\"3\"       ", "\"4\"       ", "\"5\"       ", "\"1\"       ", 
            "\"2\"       ", "\"3\"       ", "\"4\"       ", "\"5\"       ", 
            "\"1\"       ", "\"2\"       ", "\"3\"       ", "\"4\"       ", 
            "\"5\"       ", "\"1\"       ", "\"2\"       ", "\"3\"       ", 
            "\"4\"       ", "\"5\"       ", "\"HINCFEL\"", "         ", "         ", 
            "         ", "         ", "         ", "         ", "         ", 
            "         ", "         ", "         ", "         ", "         ", 
            "         ", "         ", "         ", "         ", "         ", 
            "         ", "         ", "         ", "         ", "         ", 
            "         ", "         ", "         ", "         ", "         ", 
            "         ", "         ", "         ", "         ", "         ", 
            "         ", "         ", "         ", "         ", "         ", 
            "         ", "         ", "         ", "         ", "         ", 
            "         ", "         ", "         ", "         ", "         ", 
            "         ", "         ", "         ", "         ", "\"1\"", 
            "   ", "  4", "  0", "  0", " 25", "  1", " 10", "  1", "  0", 
            " 12", "  3", " 28", "  1", "  0", "  2", "  1", "  7", "  0", 
            "  0", "  0", "  1", " 27", "  0", "  0", "  0", "  0", " 41", 
            "  1", "  0", "  0", "  1", "  8", "  0", "  1", "  0", "  2", 
            " 34", "  0", "  2", "  0", "  2", " 33", "  0", "  1", "  0", 
            "  1", "  1", "  0", " 13", "  0", "  3", "\"2\"", "   ", "  7", 
            "  1", "  0", " 13", "  2", " 17", "  0", "  0", "  9", "  5", 
            " 15", "  0", "  0", "  3", "  0", "  8", "  0", "  0", "  0", 
            "  0", " 44", "  1", "  0", "  0", "  1", " 29", "  0", "  0", 
            "  0", "  1", " 24", "  1", "  3", "  0", "  5", " 34", "  0", 
            "  7", "  0", "  0", " 16", "  1", "  1", "  0", "  4", "  1", 
            "  1", " 41", "  0", "  1", "\"3\"", "   ", "  1", "  1", "  0", 
            "  5", "  2", "  5", "  4", "  0", "  2", "  0", "  1", "  2", 
            "  0", "  0", "  1", " 14", "  2", "  0", "  1", "  1", " 19", 
            "  5", "  0", "  0", "  3", "  4", "  1", "  0", "  1", "  0", 
            "  8", "  2", "  2", "  0", "  6", "  9", "  0", "  2", "  0", 
            "  3", "  5", "  0", "  0", "  0", "  1", "  2", "  0", " 19", 
            "  0", "  4", "\"4\"", "   ", "  2", "  0", "  0", "  1", "  0", 
            "  0", "  0", "  0", "  1", "  0", "  0", "  0", "  0", "  0", 
            "  0", "  1", "  4", "  0", "  0", "  0", "  1", "  2", "  0", 
            "  0", "  0", "  0", "  0", "  0", "  1", "  0", "  3", "  0", 
            "  0", "  0", "  1", "  0", "  1", "  0", "  0", "  3", "  0", 
            "  2", "  0", "  0", "  0", "  0", "  2", "  1", "  0", "  1"
), .Dim = c(52L, 10L), .Dimnames = list(c("", "", "", "", "", 
                                          "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
                                          "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
                                          "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), 
                                        c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "")), class = "noquote")
```

Comment: That data is needs a fair bit of work to make it a standard matrix or data.frame before you even consider reshaping it. It looks like a matrix, but the column names are spread across three rows of the actual data. I would go back a step or two and get it imported properly from your source data first.

Comment: if it comes from an excel pivot find the option to repeat the labels, it will help